# Adding Text at a specific postion in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, full-text-search

I have a multiline text, something like this -

```
a = """
Hi this is a sample line
Another line
Final line of the example.
"""
```

And I have a text value -

```
b = '00000000'       # to insert in between
```

I need to insert the string b into string a at specific position, say **(2,1)** (i.e. line 2, char 1), since this is how I am getting the result of pattern match from some module (in form of line_number, char_number in line).

Expected Output -

```
a = """
Hi this is a sample line
A00000000nother line                          # <-- Entered string in line 2, after char 1 i.e. (2,1)
Final line of the example.
"""
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
This is where you repeat your tutorial on string processing; it is not a Stack Overflow matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.splitlines`, change the required line and join the lines back:

```py
a = """
Hi this is a sample line
Another line
Final line of the example.
"""

b = "00000000"

pos = 2, 1

lines = a.splitlines()
lines[pos[0]] = lines[pos[0]][: pos[1]] + b + lines[pos[0]][pos[1] :]

print("\n".join(lines))
```

Prints:

```
Hi this is a sample line
A00000000nother line
Final line of the example.
```